# Difference between hashing commands in Linux

Tags: java, linux, hash

I am trying to get passwords hashes encoded in base64 for a login database. I am using the picketbox security library to get the base64 encoded hashes of the passwords, but I would like to get a different tool.

1. If I use:

   ```
   java -cp $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.9.6.Final.jar org.jboss.security.Base64Encoder  master SHA-256
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   [/GE7Tf1nNqe9JoyKDnTtDRwEqVn1nddO8odJg/1EP8k=];
   ```

   `[` `]` must be removed in database to log in properly.
2. When I use:

   ```
    echo -n master | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   /GE7Tf1nNqe9JoyKDnTtDRwEqVn1nddO8odJg/1EP8k=
   ```

The same result.

3. However when I use:

   ```
   echo -n master |sha256sum -b | base64
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   ZmM2MTNiNGRmZDY3MzZhN2JkMjY4YzhhMGU3NGVkMGQxYzA0YTk1OWY1OWRkNzRlZjI4NzQ5ODNmZDQ0M2ZjOSAqLQo=
   ```

What is the difference between  `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary` and `sha256sum -b`? I thought they would provide the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the difference between `openssl` and `sha256sum`:

- `openssl` prints the hash in raw binary. It's not text, it's not human readable, it's pure bytes:

  ```
  $ echo -n master | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary
  �Y��N�I��D?�
  ```

  If you count the bytes with `wc ---bytes` you'll see it's printing exactly 32 bytes:

  ```
  $ echo -n master | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | wc --bytes
  32
  ```

  We can also convert it to hex with `hexdump`:

  ```
  $ echo -n master | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | hexdump
  0000000 61fc 4d3b 67fd a736 26bd 8a8c 740e 0ded
  0000010 041c 59a9 9df5 4ed7 87f2 8349 44fd c93f
  0000020
  ```
- By contrast, `sha256sum` prints the hash in human readable form in hexadecimal using the digits `0-9` and the letters `a-f`.

  ```
  $ echo -n master | sha256sum -b
  fc613b4dfd6736a7bd268c8a0e74ed0d1c04a959f59dd74ef2874983fd443fc9 *-
  ```

  It's the same information as the garbled binary above but it's presented differently. You'll notice that the hex value takes up a lot more space than the binary data. It also includes the file name at the end, which here is the cryptic `*-`. `*` means you used the `-b` flag, while `-` denotes that the input was read from stdin.

You can get the same hex value from `openssl` if you change `-binary` to `-hex`:

```
$ echo -n master | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex
(stdin)= fc613b4dfd6736a7bd268c8a0e74ed0d1c04a959f59dd74ef2874983fd443fc9
```

There's no way to do the reverse, though. `sha256sum` doesn't have a flag to print a binary hash. It can only do hex.